# Int и bool из С++. Как портировать на C#?

Tags: c#, c++

У меня есть вот такая строчка в С++ коде: `sects[low].bound = low`.
Где low это size_t, sects это `std::vector<Section>`, а Section это структура с булевым полем bound.

```
struct Section {
   //другой код
   bool bound;
};
```

Это безобразие надо портировать на C# с чем я почти справился. Смущает только эта часть: 
`sects[low].bound = low;`

Немного погуглив нашел что в C++ все целые не равные нулю преобразуются к true, а равные нулю к false, и C# код выглядит так:`sects[low].Bound = low > 0;`

Прав ли я? Если нет то как надо?

Comment: `sects[low].Bound = low != 0`. Отрицательные тоже false. Тут конечно не может быть отрицательных по определению, но для полного соответствия нужно.

Comment: [Только 0 будет false](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.bool#1)

Comment: @John думаю, вы имели в виду "отрицательные тоже `true`"

Comment: @Tocic Опечатался, очевидно же)